# Obtaining points with equal spacing from interpolated data

Tags: interpolation

Beginning with five ordered pairs I made an interpolation, obtaining an a polynomial expression.

I got several other points with equal spacing from the polynomial expression. Are there any commands more specific to doing this operation?

Here is my code.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {12, 25}, {27, 52}, {33, 45}, {42, 31}};
eq = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
xPoint = Range[0, 50, 2];
yPoint = Table[eq, {x, xPoint}];
positions = Transpose[{xPoint, yPoint}];
ListPlot[positions]
```

Comment: See this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127096/how-to-derive-interpolate-a-polynomial-fx-y-from-several-discrete-polynomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by simplifying the code:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {12, 25}, {27, 52}, {33, 45}, {42, 31}};

eq = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];

ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 50, 2], 
   Table[eq, {x, Range[0, 50, 2]}]}]]
```

Comment: You haven't defined `xPoint`.

Comment: Now yes is helpful. Unfortunately came too late.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you want the interpolated points for further processing, because there is little reason to make the interpolation otherwise. I would proceed as follows:

1. I get the fitted polynomial as function `f`. I use `Block` to protect the variable `x` from any previous assignment.

   ```
   data = {{0, 0}, {12, 25}, {27, 52}, {33, 45}, {42, 31}};
   Block[{x}, f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]];
   ```
2. I compute the points directly in a table.

   ```
   pts = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, 0, 50, 2}];
   ```
3. I plot the interpolated points along with the data to check my work.

   ```
   ListPlot[pts, Prolog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[data]}]
   ```

[image: plot]

The extrapolation of the data beyond 42 is suspect.

Comment: Extrapolation was on purpose

Comment: @user43142. I don't doubt it, but the extrapolation is simply not trustworthy unless you have some reason beyond the five data points to expect the sharp upward turn beyond 42.

Answer (score 5):

`Table` is enough:

```
Table[{x, eq}, {x, 1, 50, 2}] // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If your intention is to plot the points then you can also use `Mesh`:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {12, 25}, {27, 52}, {33, 45}, {42, 31}};
eq = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];

pl = Plot[
  Evaluate[eq], {x, 0, 50},
  PlotStyle -> None,
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], ColorData[97][1]],
  Mesh -> 25
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also retrieve the actual points like this:

```
Cases[Normal[pl], Point[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]
```

although this is a roundabout way to get the points, not really simpler than what you used. However, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84385/731), this could be the way to go if you want to generate points that are equally spaced along the curve rather than equally spaced on the x axis.